# Can I get stored procedure script back from Model.edmx file in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have deleted SQL Server database accidentally and this database was used with an ASP.NET MVC project. I am using Entity Framework for database connectivity. I do not have any database backup but I am able to get all table scripts from `Model.edmx` file with the following steps:

1. Open model browser
2. Right click on `.store` file
3. Select generate database from model now it produce SQL query of all table like this:

[image]

So my question is that can I also get the stored procedure scripts like the tables?

I am attaching screenshot for reference. In below screenshot there is a section of stored procedure/function from this section there is list of stored procedure which I was using.

My question is if and how can I generate the SQL code?

[image]

Comment: How did you deploy the SP's with your web application from the onset?

Comment: This project was developed locally in visual studio and connected with SQL server via Entity framework so I was adding SP in SQL and get reference of that SP in project by entity framework by updating model

Comment: " I do not have any database backup" - I'm going to have to ask why?

Comment: Resion for asking is that is there any possibility to get sql script for store procedure like table...here i have clearly mentioned that we are able to get all table script if we have model.edmx files even we have lost our sql database

Comment: No, this is not possible, the EDMX only represents the return values from the stored procedures. You need a backup or CREATE PROCEDURE scripts.